# How to change the date of a Calendar instance in Java?

Tags: java, date, calendar, date-formatting

I have a class `DayOfWeek` which takes a date from the user and prints the day of the week on that date.

For example the user will enter his date as: (with the format `MM DD YYYY`)

```
07 22 2016
```

and the output should be

> FRIDAY

This is my class:

```
public class DayOfWeek{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter the date (Format: MM DD YYYY) :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String month = sc.next();
        String day = sc.next();
        String year = sc.next();
        int m = Integer.parseInt(month);
        int d = Integer.parseInt(day);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(year);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date(y, m, d);
        cal.setTime(date);
        int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        System.out.println((sdf.format(dayOfWeek)).toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

However when I enter the date stated above (`07 22 2016`), I don't get the required output (`FRIDAY`). Instead the output is the current day of week on my system. I am totally stuck on what the problem is.

Comment: Tip: [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). You are using troublesome old legacy classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're currently passing an `int` to `SimpleDateFormat`... you should pass the `Date` value. You don't need a `Calendar` at all for that:

```
// BAD CODE: DON'T USE - KEEP READING
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DayOfWeek {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter the date (Format: MM DD YYYY) :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String month = sc.next();
        String day = sc.next();
        String year = sc.next();
        int m = Integer.parseInt(month);
        int d = Integer.parseInt(day);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(year);
        // Note the changes here
        Date date = new Date(y - 1900, m - 1, d);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date).toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

I've put the warning there because you're using a deprecated Date constructor - and it's deprecated for good reasons. Basically, `java.util.Date` is a *terrible* API and you should avoid using it if you possibly can. Your original call to `new Date(y, m, d)` was broken because the first parameter to `java.util.Date(int, int, int)` represents the year with a 1900 base (so a value of 117 means year 2017) and the second parameter represents the month with a 0 base (so a value of 6 means July). Then there's the implicit time zone conversion, which you really don't want.

You'd be *much* better off using `java.time`, and in this case the `LocalDate` class:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DayOfWeek {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter the date (Format: MM DD YYYY) :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String month = sc.next();
        String day = sc.next();
        String year = sc.next();
        int m = Integer.parseInt(month);
        int d = Integer.parseInt(day);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(year);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(y, m, d);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE");
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date).toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Finally, your approach to parsing the user input isn't ideal either - I'd suggest using a `DateTimeFormatter` for that, too:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public class DayOfWeek {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter the date (Format: MM DD YYYY) :");
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM dd yyyy");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(line, parser);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE");
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date).toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: In fairness, java.util.Date was part of Java 1.0.  In 1995, nobody had a good Date API.

Comment: @VGR: It wouldn't have been hard to work out that that API was bad in many ways though...

Comment: Actually that `Date` API was already pre-existing, before Java. See source code for copyright notice by [Taligent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taligent)/IBM.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Sure, but that's no excuse for perpetuating it IMO.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution did the job perfectly. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

if you need the output to be Tue rather than 3 (Days of week are indexed starting at (1), instead of going through a calendar, just reformat the `string:  new SimpleDateFormat("EE").format(date)` (EE meaning "day of week, short version").

**Note**
As pointed by Jon Try and use the latest Date Time Formatter Api for this purpose the Date Api is depricated .

If you have your input as string, rather than Date, you should use SimpleDateFormat to parse it

```
: new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy").parse(dateString)
```

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` you've suggested doesn't match the instructions the code prints out. I'd also strongly advise against recommending the legacy date/time classes at all, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes i will mark it right way thanks for pointing out

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

[@JonSkeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266427/7605325) is correct and already explains all the problems of the old API and how to use the new one. I'd just like to add another approach with `java.time` classes.

If you want just to get a `String` with the day of the week, you can skip the creation of a `LocalDate` and get directly a `java.time.DayOfWeek`.

The first part is the same (get the input from the `Scanner` and create a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse it).

Then I create a `java.time.DayOfWeek` from the parsed input, using the `from` method. So I call `getDisplayName`, using `java.time.format.TextStyle` (which is equivalent to `EEEE` format in [@JonSkeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266427/7605325)) and a `java.util.Locale` to make it explicit that I want the day of week's names in English.

```
// read line from input
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
// get "07 22 2016" from the scanner
String line = sc.nextLine();
// formatter to parse the input
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM dd yyyy");
// get the day of the week
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(parser.parse(line));
// get day of week's name
String output = dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH).toUpperCase();
```

The value of `output` variable will be `FRIDAY` - note that I also called `toUpperCase()`, because the result of `getDisplayName` is `Friday`.

The `Locale` is also important. If you don't specify a locale, it'll use the system's default, and **it's not guaranteed to always be English**. And it can also be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to make it explicit in your code.

---

**Notes:**

- The code above will also work if you want to change the language (just use a different `Locale`). But if you always want an English uppercase name, you can optionally call `dow.toString()`, which will also return `FRIDAY` as well.
- This code focus only on the day of the week. If you need to use the date for other things than getting `FRIDAY` (like checking the day, month, etc), then you'll need a `LocalDate` and [@JonSkeet's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266427/7605325) is preferred (and `LocalDate` has the method `getDayOfWeek()`, which returns the corresponding `DayOfWeek`, just in case you need it).
- `java.time` is available only in Java >= 8. If you're using Java <= 7, though, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). The only difference is the package name (`org.threeten.bp` instead of `java.time`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.